# Xamarin Forms controls losing their style

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am building an app in xamarin forms. Issue i have is that when attached to the debugger, everything looks good. Once i detach from the debugger, some of the controls seem to lose their stye. See attached images.

| When attached to debugger | When not attached to the debugger |
| --- | --- |
| [image: When attached to debugger] | [image: When not attached to the debugger] |

Any ideas as to what is happening here ?. Thanks

Comment: Without code, we can just speculate so i would suggest you add more details

Comment: There is no code behind these. I have not set the style myself. Just plain old xaml. No C# behind them. 
<SwitchCell Text="Receive Push Notifications" On="false" />

Comment: Where did you set the breakpoint?

Comment: Sorry i havent got enough detail but its hard to say whats going on. Phone plugged in to pc for testing, all good. Disconnect the phone and sooner or later the change happens. Not break points, not setting of anything. This even did this with the stock Xamarin forms startup app

Comment: You could update your question once you get more detail, it is hard to find out what is going on with what you give now.

Comment: To be honest, i was just hoping for a speculatory guess. Considering the fact that if i create a new Xamarin forms app and it displays this problem without me changing anything at all, i'm at a loss as to what code would possibly be helpful. Maybe its a problem with the VS install that i'm using. Anyway i'll have to look into how all the styling is set up and will post here if i find anything. Thanks

Comment: Ok. Found the problem. Was to do with colours that were set not working with the device OS's light and dark theme. Funny how the default vs app had it wrong. Anyway that was it. Thanks all for having a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the problem. Was to do with colours that were set not working with the device OS's light and dark theme. Need to be careful what text colours are set and how they play nicely with dark light changes